# Want to Run VB.Net Desktop Application in web Browser as Web Application

Tags: vb.net

I have a Small ERP Financial Software developed in VB.Net and SQL Server consisting on modules
HRM, Accounts, General Ledger etc.

Now i want to run some module on web but Creating all application in asp.net or other web tools is too much time taking.

Is There any way to run this Desktop application on web espacially in Web Browsers. ?

Any Help.

Comment: You can create such application in WPF but the limitation is that it will run only on intranet and supports only IE and Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-write your application you could have a look at [Go Global](http://www.resource-dynamics.com/goglobal.asp).

I can't vouch for it as I have personally never used it, but I know of people who have.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that for a proof of concept on the past and it runs great.  Called .net zero deployment, you can look it up.  The only concern is off you need database access, remember that you are paying through the port 80, so a need for a web service to access database call may be needed.  Not sure of I have still the code trial, but I can look.